# Різниця між вживанням слів «являється» та «є»

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Яка різниця між вживанням слів «являється» та «є»? У Вікіпедії знайшла інформацію, що «являється» - це граматична калька з російської мови, але там немає жодних пояснень.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вважається калькою з російської, тому що є відповідне слово у російській мові. До прикладу стаття, у якій розтлумачено в якому сенсі могли вжити слово *являється* українці.

[Являтися — бути (є) — являти собою (Роксолана Ткачук)](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine48-49-38.pdf)

> На уроці української мови вчителька зауважила учневі, що вислів «Підмет являється головним членом речення» є неправильним, бо слова *являється* з таким значенням в українській мові немає. Правильно сказати: «Підмет є головним членом речення» або «Підмет — головний член речення». Тоді учень здивовано запитав: «То це і І. Франко
>   помилився, пишучи:
>
> > Чого являєшся мені
> >     Усні?
> >     Чого звертаєш ти до мене
> >     чудові очі та ясні,
> >     сумні,
> >     Немов криниці дно студене?».
>
> Ні, І. Франко не помилився, бо вживав дієслово *являтися* у значенні «поставати в уяві, приходити в думках, уявлятися». Так воно фіксується у словниках і широко використовується в художньому мовленні, пор.: «То *являлась* вона йому з грушею в руці, то стояла вона перед ним вся прозора й рожева» (І. Нечуй-Левицький); «Я не знаю, чого ще та смерть захотіла? Всюди радість нового життя, А вона й тут *являється* сміло, Як змія...»
>   (В. Полішук).
>
> Уживання дієслова *являтися* замість дієслова-зв’язки є (форма теперішнього часу від *бути*) помилкове. Воно поширилося в українській мові під впливом російської. Зовсім неприйнятними для українського вжитку є речення: *Він являється членом комісії; Чи не являється наше сьогоднішнє зубожіння наслідком духовного занепаду?* Правильно було б
>   сказати: *Він є членом комісії; Чи не є наше сьогоднішнє зубожіння наслідком духовного занепаду?*
>
> У книжному вжитку, зокрема в науковому стилі, поряд із дієсловом-зв’язкою **є** часто використовується дієслово-зв’язка *являти собою*, яка поєднується з іменником лише в знахідному відмінку, пор.: «Аміакати *являють собою* розчин аміачної або кальцієвої селітри в рідкому аміаку» (З газ.); «Кожен день у житті людини *являє собою* певний крок у її
>   становленні» (Людина і суспільство. Підручник).
>
> Отже, в українській мові дієслово *являтися* виражає значення «поставати в уяві, уявлятися, приходити в думках». І не використовується як дієслово-зв’язка в складному присудку. Роль зв’язок виконують дієслово *бути* та словосполучення *являти собою*.

Comment: Додав цитату, бо ланки можуть «вмирати». Ваші виправки також вніс.